# Setting the content property of the TabItem with a VieModel in Josh Smith's MVVM sample

Tags: wpf, mvvm

As many others, I started my MVVM journey by reading [Josh Smith's MVVM Demo.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Using typed Data Template, he mapped every xxxViewModel to xxxView, so every time a ViewModel object is rendered, the appropriate View object is displayed. 
What I could not understand (nor find in the source code) is where does he actually set the Content property of the TabItem with a ViewModel?

N.B

Being new with WPF also, I am not sure my question is directly related to the MVVM pattern...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He sets the `ItemSource` property of the TabControl to an observable collection of `ViewModels`, which he then uses the DataTemplate to link up to views. Check the section a couple of code blocks down from Figure 7. I don't think he explicitly shows that code in the example figures though.